# how to hide shipping and billing address when a specific shipping method is selected in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

How can I hide 'Shipping' and 'Billing' fields at Woocommerce checkout page, if a user selected a specific shipping method, for example, self-collection. For self-collection, these fields are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the possible solution for your query

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','your_fun_name');

function your_fun_name( $needs_address ) {
        if($payment_method == 'self-collection') {
            $needs_address = false;
        }
        return $needs_address;
}
```

Comment: Hi @MakeWebBetter, thank you for this. It helps a lot as i don't have solid  programming background. 

Just one more thing, 

https://mistydaydream.com/checkout/

On this page, i have set according to your way but it only works when self-collection is selected and refreshing the page. How can i check if there is any changes in user selection for shipping method, to re-run the function?

Comment: As you know after selecting different shipping methods at checkout page WooCommerce only changes the content of the woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table table, then it would be quite complex to hide the fields through hooks, there is an another option, we can localize the data in the js and check if the user has selected that particular shipping method then we can hide it through JavaScript.